# Inserting intermediate values between min value and max value without using loops

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a very large dataset that requires me to use PySpark to process it. I have a table that looks like this. Here is a small sample:

```
minutes | hour 
718       11    
719       11
721       12 
722       12 
723       12 
779       12
781       13
782       13
```

What I need to do is have a table that calculates all the minute intervals and have the hour as the columns like this:

```
11 | 12 | 13 
2    60   2
```

First problem is the missing values. I will need to add the values (720, 11), (720,12), (780,12), (780, 13) in order to calculate the minute intervals for each hour. Once I add those values, I can do a group by hour and find the difference between the minimum minutes and maximum minutes. I can then do a pivot by hour.

Any ideas with appending those values without using loops or hardcoding? I just need to have this as the output.

```
minutes | hour 
718       11    
719       11
720*      11
720*      12
721       12 
722       12 
723       12 
779       12
780*      12
780*      13
781       13
782       13
```

Comment: Can you give more details about you df? What minutes column means?

Comment: @LuizViola the minutes is the timestamp converted to minutes. Range is from 0 to 1440

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.